# Spring Boot with multiple database using hibernate and JpaRepository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to implement multiple database configurations in Spring Boot ???
how to create spring Boot MVC Application with 2 different databases using hibernate ???

application.properties(DB1=core,DB2=staging)

```
server.port=8772


spring.core.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.core.url=jdbc:mysql://ip:port/coredb
spring.core.username=uname
spring.core.password=pwd


spring.staging.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.staging.url=jdbc:mysql://ip:port/stagingdb
spring.staging.username=uname
spring.staging.password=pwd
```

Repository :

```
public interface IStagingEntityDao  extends   
JpaRepository<StagingEmployee, Integer>{ 

      Query("select e from StagingEmployee e")
      public List<StagingEmployee> getEntityData();

}
```

DBConfig :

```
public class DBConfig {

    @Bean(name="stagingDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.staging")
    public DataSource stagingDataSource()
    {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="coreDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.core")
    public DataSource coreDataSource()
    {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Requirement :

I just want to copy data from one db to another
consider employee as entity i want to copy data from db1 to db2
what i have done so far is i have create controller(@RestController) and service and repository which get data from db 1 and push it in db2 by calling respective service in single spring boot app itself.

Exception : 
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.

Whats is missing in above configurations ????

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it usefull

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

It shows how to define multiple datasources & assign one of them as primary.

Here is a rather full example, also contains distributes transactions - if you need it.

http://fabiomaffioletti.me/blog/2014/04/15/distributed-transactions-multiple-databases-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-atomikos/

What you need is to create 2 configuration classes, separate the model/repository packages etc to make the config easy.

Also, in above example, it creates the data sources manually. You can avoid this using the method on spring doc, with @ConfigurationProperties annotation. Here is an example of this:

http://xantorohara.blogspot.com.tr/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html

Hope these helps

Comment: i tried with two different datasource as primary and secondary but its not working.it gives "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath."

Comment: Can u change the spring.xx.url to spring.xx.jdbcUrl and try agin ?

Comment: Gokhan Oner tried but same result. i guess i am missing some more configurations. With respect to db access i have only above 3 configurations ir app.properties,Respository interface which extends Jparepository and DBConfig.java which creates 2 datasource as shown above nothing else for database access.

Comment: Can you put your project to github or share  so i can look ??

Comment: due to some reason i cant share project.but i can explain you.Whats exactly i need to achive i explain in brief in my question refer edit.

Comment: if you have any other way to do it with spring boot that would be fine.

Comment: Ok, I think I  found your problem. First, spring-boot configures only 1 Entity manager, transaction manager etc. But you need 2 of them, so you need to configure them all by yourself, like in the example:

http://fabiomaffioletti.me/blog/2014/04/15/distributed-transactions-multiple-databases-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-atomikos/

Please read this post carefully. It contains some additional features like Distributed transactions but apart from that, it's basically what you needed. I'll put a sample project to github in 2 days so you can also look it as well..

Comment: i have done some changes to configurations now its working.I want know that how would 2 different Repository would get know that which data source they are suppose to use from above config file as i have not specified any annotation on repository interface which extending JpaRepository.

Comment: Well, you need to look to the link i send. You need to overwrite the default config and let the config know which ds, transac.manager, entity manager etc. it shoul use.

Comment: i have seen the link. what i have seen in that is for mapping it is given as @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.at.mul.repository.order") which i guess is responsible for mapping or understanding between repository and its respective datasource . if i am wrong please correct me but if that is the case if repository belongs to 2 different dbs are in same package than how could this thing will work  @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.at.mul.repository.order") . ??????

Comment: You're correct, but you need to define 2 different Repositories for 2 DBs. Also entityManager.setPackagesToScan("com.at.mul.domain.customer"); is important, it show the entity scan package. And I'm not sure if you can use same entities for different Configs. here another example: https://github.com/gratiartis/multids-demo